# laravel 4 form open and route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have problem with action in {{ Form::open() }}

> Route [adm/tagedit] not defined.

My code in view is

```
 {{ Form::open(['method'=>'post','action'=>"adm/tagedit"])}}
        {{ Form::submit('edit',['class'=>'btn btn-default']) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

and in routes

```
Route::get('adm/{action?}/{params?}',function($action,$params=null){
if(Auth::check()==false||Auth::user()->isAdmin()==false){
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('/')->withError('Youe need be logged in');
}
return  (new AdmController())->{$action}($params);
```

});

```
//routing for bacend post method
Route::post('adm/{action?}/{params?}',['before'=>'csrf',function($action,$params=null){
    if(Auth::check()==false||Auth::user()->isAdmin()==false){
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('/')->withError('You need be logged in');
    }
    return  (new AdmController())->{$action.'Post'}($params);
}]);
```

Of course if I use get request action work. In controller I use action "tageditPost"

Probably my problem is similar to Rediredt:route() is not work too. But in redirect I use Reditect:to() and work fine. In form, I don't know what should I change.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 {{ Form::open(['method'=>'post','url'=>"adm/tagedit"]) }}
     {{ Form::submit('edit',['class'=>'btn btn-default']) }}
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Thanks you it works  tell me please, if is possible use Redirect:route acne action in form for regex routing? Or it is possible only with fixed routes

Comment: only fixed routes/URL/controller action in forms.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Regards Jarek